# Multiple Instances of the same ASP.NET Web App in IIS

Tags: asp.net, session

I have a ASP.NET WebForms app that I have deployed twice to the same IIS server. One is for production and the other is for test.

They each point to different databases, that is the only difference between the source of the two apps.

When I sign-in to PRODUCTION, it works fine. Then I sign-in to TEST and it works fine too. When I go back to PRODUCTION, the session seems to have terminated and I need to sign-in again. When I sign-in again, it terminates the session in TEST.

Seems like I can't have both PRODUCTION and TEST sessions at the same time. Are their sessions somehow linked?

I've tried hosting each one in its own app pool and its own web site. Why does signing-in into the one terminate the others session?

Comment: Are you using In Memory for Session? Or is it backed by SQL Server or some other storage? Does each site have its own application pool, or are they on the same one?

Comment: I'm using an "in memory" session and each site is using its own app pool.